# Password text field Visibility section Not Work in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

Why is the icon.Filled.Visibility section of the visibility section not recognized when I use password text filled? Should I add an implementation? Also, the VisibilityOff section is not recognized, please help me

```
var password by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }
var passwordHidden by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(true) }
TextField(
    value = password,
    onValueChange = { password = it },
    singleLine = true,
    label = { Text("Enter password") },
    visualTransformation =
    if (passwordHidden) PasswordVisualTransformation() else VisualTransformation.None,
    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Password),
    trailingIcon = {
        IconButton(onClick = { passwordHidden = !passwordHidden }) {
            val visibilityIcon =
                if (passwordHidden) Icons.Filled.Visibility else Icons.Filled.VisibilityOff
            // Please provide localized description for accessibility services
            val description = if (passwordHidden) "Show password" else "Hide password"
            Icon(imageVector = visibilityIcon, contentDescription = description)
        }
    }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the normal `androidx.compose.material.icons.Icons` doesn't contain it by default and you will have to add it using two ways:

1. first approach is adding this dependency to you project that all the additional icons:

   `dependencies { ... implementation "androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended:$compose_version" }`
2. is to add it manually from the icons of android studio and you do that by :
   go to `res/drawable` folder then right mouse click then `New/Vector Asset` a window with pop up containing the android logo by default click on the logo besides `Clip Art` section a window will pop up with the name select icon then you search for what ever icon you want after that click `Ok` then `Next` then `Finish`
   now the icon is added to you drawable folder you can use it like this:

   `Icon(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.name_of_icon), contentDescription = "")`

**Note: make sure the the R used is from you package name.**